# Copy single file to several subfolders

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I am trying to copy a single file to several subfolders.
Both file and subfolders already exists.
I keep getting the run time error 70: permission denied when I run my code.

I have administrator rights, have also tried to run my code in excel administrator mode and have checked that the folders does not have the read only attribute.

And I created all the subfolders with a vba script so I am really puzzled...
Why did I not get the same error that time?

This is the code I have trouble with...

```
Sub LoopSubFoldersAndCopyPasteFile()

Dim fso As Object
Dim folder As Object
Dim subfolders As Object
Dim MyFile As Object

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set folder = fso.Getfolder("\\SRV-FIL01\Users$\CVS\Desktop\Nye Protokoller\2013\")
Set subfolders = folder.subfolders


For Each subfolders In subfolders

    Set MyFile = fso.Getfile("\\SRV-FIL01\Users$\CVS\Desktop\Protokoller\TyskeProtokoller_2013.xlsx")
    SetAttr MyFile, vbNormal
    SetAttr subfolders, vbNormal

    fso.CopyFile MyFile, subfolders

Next

'Release memory
Set fso = Nothing
Set folder = Nothing
Set subfolder = Nothing

End Sub
```

I expected to have the MyFile copied to all the subfolders, but instead I got the run time error 70: Permission denied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will fix your issue

```
Sub LoopSubFoldersAndCopyPasteFile()

Dim fso As Object
Dim folder As Object
Dim subfolders As Object
Dim MyFile As Object

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set folder = fso.GetFolder("\\SRV-FIL01\Users$\CVS\Desktop\Nye Protokoller\2013\")
'Set subfolders = folder.subfolders

Dim fld As obejct
For Each fld In folder.subfolders

    Set MyFile = fso.GetFile("\\SRV-FIL01\Users$\CVS\Desktop\Protokoller\TyskeProtokoller_2013.xlsx")
    SetAttr MyFile, vbNormal
    SetAttr fld, vbNormal

    fso.CopyFile MyFile.Path, fld.Path & "\" & MyFile.Name

Next

End Sub
```